# Low budget clone movie with a sheriff tricking a guard by saying 'clowns'

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this movie circa 1980.  All I remember is that a clone escaped from the clone "factory", and managed to contact the local sheriff.  The sheriff drives up to the compound gate, tricks the security guard by asking "I hear you have some clowns in here" (or something like that).  The guard replies "You mean clones", which gives the game away.  The sheriff then crashes through the gate with his truck, with the usual mayhem.

I thought that the actor who played the sheriff was David Huddleston, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I've searched high and low for the name of this movie, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, it *is* David Huddleston. You're looking for [Computercide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083753/combined) (AKA The Final Eye) from 1981.

> The year is 1995 and Michael Stringer is the only private eye left on Earth. One day, he is assigned by a woman to investigate Eden Isle, a complex for people who want a perfect life started by an industrialist named Korter. Interestingly, Korter is found on a beach and is 20 years younger than he was before. When he gets into the complex, he is caught in a web of mystery that he might not get out of.

It ends up being a clone farm, and near the end, Stringer comes across a chief of police (who keeps insisting he's *not* a sheriff, though) played by Huddleston. Stringer tries to tells him about the cloning, but the chief think he says *clowning*. They then drive to the complex, where this dialogue takes place between the chief and the guard:

> **Chief:** Found one of your people wandering along the highway. Thought I'd better bring him on in. Kept yammering about something called *'clowning'.*
>
> **Guard:** *Cloning?*
>
> **Chief:** Ain't that something. You catch on real fast.

Once the jig is up, the Chief crashes through the gate in his truck. Donald Pleasance plays the villain, BTW (as per usual). The movie is currently available on Youtube and the scene is around minute 78.